# How can I load multiple Chartjs charts with different data on the same page?

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

I have a website and some charts built with chart js. The data for the charts is all in one file, *births.js*. Before, there were multiple pages, so to load the correct chart I used a function and if statement for each page

```
    function drawChart() {
       if (window.location.href.indexOf("scotland") > -1) {
    } 
    else if(window.location.href.indexOf("index") > -1){
    }
```

etc.

I've now been tasked with having everything on one interactive page, so the indexOf will always just be *index*. Is there a way to rewrite the function so that I can load the different data on the same page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, then you can use different ids for different charts.not even this every jquery or js plugin can be used like this.

```
  <canvas id="yourid1" width="400" height="400"></canvas><canvas id="yourid2" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
var ctx = document.getElementById("yourid2");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels:......///and so on for your another charts
    var ctx = document.getElementById("yourid1");
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels:.......///not the complete code. just reference
```

same again with another id for different charts

```
<canvas id="yourid2" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
var ctx = document.getElementById("yourid2");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels:......///and so on for your another charts
```